Really struggling to record video + sound on PC, can anybody steer me in right direction?
This is what I'm trying to acheive:
Record myself playing guitar with 3 microphones. They are USB condenser microphones plugged into my PC
One channel for voice in the middle, and 2 channels for right and left guitar (1 microphone on sound hole and one pointing at the neck)
This is for classical guitar, so no direct input into PC
After the recording is done, I want to be able to adjust the balance on the left and right guitar so it's mixed evenly in stereo.
I have OBS studio and Audacity, but will get whatever software I need.
How can I acheive this?

After the recording is done - with OBS you won't be able to change anything in the resulting video file. You can do this while recording with OBS, but if you want to edit separate recordings from each source, OBS is not the right tool.

Ok thanks, so what kind of tools should I use to acheive this?

There are already questions about video editing software: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/free-video-editing-software
